# shuffling elements in a QStringList

Tags: c++, list, qt, shuffle, qstring

In my Qt c++ application I have a QStringList containing a set of QString values! I want to shuffle(change the positions of the QStrings in the QStringList arbitrarily) . Is there any default function like "shuffle_array" API in perl? If not how can I do it?

eg-

```
QStringList names;
names<<"John"<<"Smith"<<"Anne";
```

shuffling may change the positions of John,Smith and Anne arbitrarily! How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard [`std::random_shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) function:

```
std::random_shuffle(names.begin(), names.end());
```

Also, don't forget to generate a new random number sequence, otherwise the same results will be produced every time:

```
#include <time.h>

// ...

qsrand(time(NULL));
```